# linker command failed at fastmath installing pycrypto on OSX

Tags: python, pip, fabric, pycrypto

I did `pip install pycrypto` (actually wanted to install `fabric` but it failed at pycrypto) and got the error below. I'm on python 2.7.3. Tried 3.3 too but same error. How do I fix this please?

My clang version:

```
$ clang --version
Apple clang version 4.1 (tags/Apple/clang-421.11.66) (based on LLVM 3.1svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin11.4.2
Thread model: posix
```

Error:

```
...

creating build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature

copying lib/Crypto/Signature/__init__.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature

copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_PSS.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature

copying lib/Crypto/Signature/PKCS1_v1_5.py -> build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/Signature

running build_ext

running build_configure

building 'Crypto.PublicKey._fastmath' extension

creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7

creating build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/src

cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -I/usr/local/include -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -std=c99 -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -Isrc/ -I/usr/include/ -I/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c src/_fastmath.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/src/_fastmath.o

src/_fastmath.c:1545:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]

                        else if (result < 0)

                                 ~~~~~~ ^ ~

src/_fastmath.c:1621:20: warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]

                        else if (result < 0)

                                 ~~~~~~ ^ ~

2 warnings generated.

cc -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib build/temp.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/src/_fastmath.o -lgmp -o build/lib.macosx-10.7-x86_64-2.7/Crypto/PublicKey/_fastmath.so

ld: illegal text-relocation to ___gmp_binvert_limb_table in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(mp_minv_tab.o) from ___gmpn_divexact_1 in /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(dive_1.o) for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------

Command /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/folders/_2/fwbd8jjn0mj_y_9w4f31g2nm0000gn/T/pip-build/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/_2/fwbd8jjn0mj_y_9w4f31g2nm0000gn/T/pip-riA3zG-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/_2/fwbd8jjn0mj_y_9w4f31g2nm0000gn/T/pip-build/pycrypto

Exception information:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 107, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 261, in run
    requirement_set.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 1166, in install
    requirement.install(install_options, global_options)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", line 589, in install
    cwd=self.source_dir, filter_stdout=self._filter_install, show_stdout=False)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg/pip/util.py", line 612, in call_subprocess
    % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
InstallationError: Command /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python -c "import setuptools;__file__='/var/folders/_2/fwbd8jjn0mj_y_9w4f31g2nm0000gn/T/pip-build/pycrypto/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/_2/fwbd8jjn0mj_y_9w4f31g2nm0000gn/T/pip-riA3zG-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /var/folders/_2/fwbd8jjn0mj_y_9w4f31g2nm0000gn/T/pip-build/pycrypto
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an HPC version of gcc. So I removed that and reinstalled Command Line Tools in Xcode. Then I was able to install pycrypto and fabric.